# how to display only selected columns and ignore empty cells in html table using ngFor

Tags: html, angular

I am trying to display specific columns in table in angular 2. So my table element looks like this:

```html
<table class="ui single line table" id="tablej">
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let row of data;let i=index">
            <td *ngFor="let val of row;let j=index" >
                <div *ngIf="j<=2 || j==9 || j==17||j==20||j==21">
                    {{val}}
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I am getting empty spaces for skipped columns and my table became uneven. Is there any way to display specific columns and ignore the rest?

Comment: Make use of a pipe to filter based on the index

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your tr within a template tag to display or not display that column:

```
   <template *ngFor="let row of data;let i=index">
      <tr *ngIf="condition to display this column">
        <td *ngFor="let val of row;let j=index" >   
          <div *ngIf="j<=2 || j==9 || j==17||j==20||j==21">
            {{val}}
           </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
   </template>
```

The conditional row might be:

```
 <template *ngFor="let row of data;let i=index">
          <tr *ngIf="displayRow(row)">
            <td *ngFor="let val of row;let j=index" >
                {{val}}
            </td>
          </tr>
 </template>

 public displayRow(row):boolean {
    return row.length <= 2 || row.length == 9 || row.length == 17 || row.length == 20 || row.length == 21 
 }
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Hi kimy82. That is setting condition on rows. I want to set condition based on j. Basically I don't want empty columns

Comment: I see. Then the condition might call a method within your angular controller. I have changed the answer to reflect that

Comment: Better use the tag `<ng-container>` instead of `<template>`. The `<template>` tag will mess up your HTML since it's rendered in the DOM tree as a node. `<ng-container>` however is a logical container that can be used to group nodes but is not rendered in the DOM tree as a node. `<ng-container>` is rendered as an HTML comment.